# how can I get, update and delete Quota of Plan Service of Custom resource provider for Windows Azure Pack

Tags: c#, azure, azure-pack

I am working on creating new custom resource provider in windows azure pack and I followed below (link) blog and its related blogs-

http://blogs.technet.com/b/privatecloud/archive/2014/04/23/custom-resource-providers-in-windows-azure-pack-moving-from-hello-world-to-your-own-resource-provider.aspx

My question is - how to write code for Plan Quota in my custom resource provider like Retrieving Plan Quota, Updating Plan Quota and deleting Plan Quota.

Attached is the sql custom resource provider Quota UI which comes by-default with Windows Azure pack installation.

I want to get same UI and functionality for my custom resource provider as in SQL.

[image: SQL Plan Quota Screen in Windows azure pack]

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to read a series of blog posts to answer a question. It's really unclear what you're asking - please edit your question to relate it to a specific problem that you're having with code. If you can't, then it probably isn't a suitable question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Chris Mantle - I have edited this. Please tell me if you need more clarity on this

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to copy the interface of the SQL provider UI extension, and you must implement your own UI extension. You do this similarly to a normal ASP.NET website project, but it needs to be deployed in the WAP application pool.

A good example of this is given in the Hello World Custom Resource Provider, featured as a [Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479258.aspx) in the Windows Azure Pack Developers Kit. It includes both the tenant and admin portal extensions and other layers of a custom RP.

MSDN gives a reference on WAP UI extension components [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448721.aspx).

Working with plans in WAP can be done using the [Service Management REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448694.aspx), that is both admin and tenant plan interfaces. You can make calls to this API from your custom reosource provider.